# Differences when initializing app with firebase-admin using empty params, admin.credential.applicationDefault() and serviceAccount credentials

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

Considering a Firebase Cloud Function Node.js environment, in which way this:

**OPTION #1**

```
admin.initializeApp()
```

differs from this:

**OPTION #2**

```
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.applicationDefault()
});
```

or this:

**OPTION #3**

```
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
});
```

They all seem to work just fine in cloud functions that write to protected collections like this:

```
match /productsAll/{documentID} {
  allow read;
  allow write: if request.auth.token.admin == true;
}
```

Comment: Regarding that final point of "writing to protected collections", the Firestore Admin SDK will ignore any security rules and has complete read/write access.

Comment: @samthecodingman thanks! That is what I was expecting, but in some other question I have asked here, somebody mentioned the contrary. Good to confirm it! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

*The following information is based on `firebase-admin-node@8.9.0`, the current Node.js SDK at the time of posting:*

**Option 1** and **Option 2** are functionally the same for the sake of the credential used.

Whenever the `FirebaseAppOptions` object (the first parameter) does not have a `'credential'` property, it is set to `getApplicationDefault(...)`, the same as that used in the `admin.credential.applicationDefault()` method. This is the credential provided by the Google/Firebase execution environment you are running your code in.

However, in **Option 1**, the Firebase configuration variables (`databaseURL`, `databaseAuthVariableOverride`, `projectId`, etc) are all populated using the environment variable `FIREBASE_CONFIG`, whereas in **Option 2** and **Option 3**, they must be explicitly set by your code.

The `FIREBASE_CONFIG` environment variable is either a JSON string or the path to a file. In a Firebase Cloud Functions environment or a locally served project, this environment variable is populated with the relevant Firebase project's configuration.

Lastly, **Option 3** allows you to configure your own service account to use for your Admin SDK instance. You can use this to narrow the access your Admin SDK has - such as only having access to Cloud Firestore and not Cloud Storage. This is particularly useful when dealing with secondary Admin SDK instances that have a single purpose (`admin.initializeApp({...}, 'some-named-instance')`). It can also be used when you want to run your code in a testing environment rather than on your production database. It also allows you to add more scopes to other Google-owned services to the service account such as Gmail and Google Docs to simply your implementation.

Comment: You may see `functions.config().firebase` used around the place in older code. This is deprecated and used to be set to the parsed form of `FIREBASE_CONFIG` and now is just `undefined` so it doesn't mess with modern code.

Comment: If you want to run your code outside of a Google/Firebase execution environment, the application's default credentials can come from your system's `gcloud` configuration or from the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable.